# string returned from function refer to local object address

Tags: c++, string, static-analysis

I have worked on technical debts and found the below issue, maybe false positive for the below C++ code:

```
string CXXXIXMLImp::GetString(U32 val)
{
    char bufVal[64] = { 0 };
    sprintf_s(bufVal, 63, "%ld", val, 63);
    string strRetVal = bufVal;
    return strRetVal;
}
```

> error: Address of a local variable is returned via return statement expression

Note: `string` in the above is `std::string`

I have modified code at line 5 with string assign function or using string::copy. Need suggestion for the same

Comment: What compiler are you using? And does this actually have anything to do with static-analysis?

Comment: Is `string` a `std::string`? Because if it is, that's a false positive. But I kinda suspect it's something unpleasant like `typedef char const* string;`.

Comment: @StoryTeller : Eeeeww!  That would be horrible!

Comment: @MartinBonner - Yeah. I'm rooting for a false positive, I really do.

Comment: using Klocwork tool with visual studio 12.0 compiler c++. By the way string is std::string

Comment: That's a false positive.  If Klocwork fails to understand std::string, chuck it, and get a better tool.

Answer (score 1):

That's a false positive.  If Klocwork fails to understand that std::string takes a copy of its constructor argument, and then handles the copy correctly, I suggest you need a better static analysis tool.

Do *not* pollute your code with string assign or `string::copy`.  (If you can suppress it by changing the line to `const string strRetVal = buffer;` that would be OK.)